# get the last string after the special character in EditText TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, string

In edittext while entering the text

**Eg: @android @developer @stackoverflow**

I need the get the last enter character after **"@"** symbol

Expected Output from edittext **textwatcher in android**

while **typing single** word with 
**@android**

I need to extract the **android**  from textwatcher

while **typing two** word with 
**@android @developer**

I need to extract the developer from textwatcher

while **typing three** word with 
@android @developer @stackoverflow

I need to extract the stackoverflow from textwatcher

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 1):

See usage of `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()` methods

Comment: `string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("@"));` you need to handle all the corner cases

Comment: you save my day thanks